# how to merge dataframes based on column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to merge 2 dataframes with different index column names. I have df1 with the proper order of tickers that i want and would like to merge df2 witch the same tickers but in a different order and additional information.

so my df1 looks like:

### df1

| index | XOO | TSLA | FORD | YYX | AAPL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| avg | 24 | 51 | 25 | 35 | 34 |
| std | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 2 |
| min | 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| max | 78 | 78 | 97 | 89 | 97 |

### df2

| Index | 10 | 11 | 62 | 454 | 988 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ticker | AAPL | FORD | TSLA | YYX | XOO |
| sector | Tech | Auto | Tech | ETF | ETF |

My df2 has its information imported from an excel so the column names are its index numbers which I do not want. The ticker names are also in the wrong order and I need the sectors to match the tickers. The dataframe Id like to create looks like:

### df3

| index | XOO | TSLA | FORD | YYX | AAPL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| avg | 24 | 51 | 25 | 35 | 34 |
| std | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 2 |
| min | 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| max | 78 | 78 | 97 | 89 | 97 |
| sector | ETF | Tech | Auto | ETF | Tech |

I have tried to set the index using

```
Industry = Industry.set_index('Index').T.set_index('ticker').T
```

but I get an error that says "None of ['Index'] are in the columns"

I have also tried:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

but it creates a dataframe with df2 not matching the tickers and instead put it next to df1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# Import the tables you provided, which I saved as CSVs
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv', header=1)

# Rename the "ticker" column so that all it is the same as the corresponding column name in df1
df2.rename(columns={'ticker': 'index'}, inplace=True)

# Concatenate
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df3
```

Two changes to make:

1. Make sure you're selecting the correct row when you import `df2`. Use `header=1` if the column names are in row 1 of your CSV.
2. Rename the "*ticker*" column to "*index*" (so that it matches df1). That should do the trick, and the merge should work correctly.

Comment: I tried renaming the column but now in df3 the order of the tickers are the same as df2 which i do not want and the df3 has the same issues as before where it did not concatenate correctly